# Two Principal Component Vectors of 3D Vectors' Array

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, vector, statistics

I have a set of 10 3D vectors (as x,y,z values) and i was asked to find two principal component vectors of this vectors' array.

How can do it?
What are the calculations?
I couldn't be able to find a simple math operations for this problem. I found PCA functions in MATLAB and some python libraries but i was asked to do all the calculations.

Thanks for answers...

Comment: Calculate the variance-covariance matrix for the 10 vectors, then calculate the first two eigenvectors of that matrix. Those are the first two principal components.

Comment: So you had a hard time finding this info [on Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) all by yourself?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Wikipedia is restricted in our country, so yeah.

Comment: @mustaphos That sounds Turkish =D

Comment: @mustaphos Really sorry to hear that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PCA algorithm is based on calculating the first eigenvectors of the co-variance matrix of the samples.
For this purpose, you can use MATLAB's `cov`, and `eig` functions as follows:

```
X = rand(10,3) %generate samples randomly
NUM_OF_EIGENS = 2; %number of eigen vectors to extract

C = cov(X);
[principalComponents, eigenValues]=  eigs(C,NUM_OF_EIGENS);
```

The two principal components can be extracted as follows:

```
principalComponents(:,1)
principalComponents(:,2)
```